# Python scikit learn memory error for Kernel ridge

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I faced a memory error with running kernel ridge in python with the following environment,background,command. Appreciate public feedback on what could have gone wrong.

Dataset: 50k+ instances of 15 features

### Command:

```
`from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge as KRidge
svr = KRidge(alpha=1, coef0=1, kernel='linear', gamma=None, degree=3, kernel_params=None)
```

`

### Output:

**With sparse**
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\??\code.py\", line 288, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\??\code.py\", line 276, in main
    svr = model_train(X_train, Y_train, model_name)
  File "C:\??\code.py\", line 231, in model_train
    svr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\kernel_ridge.py", line 149, in fit
    K = self._get_kernel(X)
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\kernel_ridge.py", line 121, in _get_kernel
    filter_params=True, **params)
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 1399, in pairwise_kernels
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 1083, in _parallel_pairwise
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 735, in linear_kernel
    return safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 184, in safe_sparse_dot
    ret = a * b
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 369, in __mul__
    return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
  File "C:\??\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 541, in _mul_sparse_matrix
    data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
MemoryError
`

**Without sparse**


 `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\??\code.py\", line 288, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\??\code.py\", line 276, in main
        svr = model_train(X_train, Y_train, model_name)
      File "C:\??\code.py\", line 231, in model_train
        svr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
      File "C:\??\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\kernel_ridge.py", line 160, in fit
        copy)
      File "C:\??\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py", line 152, in _solve_cholesky_kernel
        overwrite_a=False)
      File "C:\??\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 178, in solve
        overwrite_b=overwrite_b
    MemoryError
```

`

Comment: Hmmm... I tried kernel regression with 40k samples and 15 features... it reached 30 GB memory before I stopped it (I have 32 GB on my PC)

Comment: Maybe try SVR `sklearn.svm.SVR` instead?

Comment: @GergesDib Yes, I was running this on my personal laptop with only 4Gb memory. I tried running on a rented AWS server with 8Gb didn't work either. Thank you for verifying even 32GB memory will likely having problem.

Comment: @GergesDib yup, already tried SVR kernel . Code  svr = SVR(kernel='poly', degree=3, coef0=0.0, tol=0.001, C=1.0, epsilon=0.1, shrinking=True, cache_size=300, verbose=False, max_iter=-1) It ran as normal with the training time: 833.2687809467316 seconds. However, the accuracy is terrible.

Comment: Have you tried tuning the SVR model? Check this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_kernel_ridge_regression.html

Comment: @GergesDib No I have not tried tuning the SVR model. I am sort of a beginner in this and attempting different models with default values before deciding which model to tune. So far the SVR model display low accuracy so didn't spend effort in tuning it.